# Strange Working of sprintf

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
int main(){
  char filepath[100];
  char datevar[15];
  char command[30];
  struct tm *t1;
  time_t now ;
  time(&now);
  memcpy(&t1,localtime(&now),sizeof(t1));
  t1 = localtime(&now);
  memset(filepath,0,sizeof(filepath));
  sprintf(datevar,"%04d%02d%02d",t1->tm_year+1900,t1->tm_mon+1,t1->tm_mday);
  strcpy(filepath,"abc");
  strcat(filepath,"/xyx/");
  strcat(filepath,datevar);
  strcat(filepath,"/");
  printf("filepath  1:- %s\n",filepath);
  sprintf(command, "hello %s good path",filepath);
  printf("filepath  2:- %s\n",filepath);
  return 0;
}
```

In the above program, both `printf` is printing different `filepath`.
output which I am getting :-

```
filepath  1:- abc/xyx/20130430/
filepath  2:- h
```

My question is why  filepath is changed if I am using it in `sprintf`.

Comment: What's up with this line:   `memcpy(&t1,localtime(&now),sizeof(t1));`?  That doesn't look right at all.

Comment: `sprintf(command, "foo %s bar", filepath);` looks terribly wrong, since `filepath` can potentially hold 100 characters, whereas `command` is only 30 characters big. Consider using `snprintf()`, by the way.

Comment: You should use `snprintf(datevar, sizeof(datevar), ` .... and of course `snprintf(command, sizeof(command)`

Comment: This is a pure C program, so I removed the C++ tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because

```
char command[30];
```

is not large enough to accommodate

```
sprintf(command, "hello %s good path",filepath);
```

It looks as though the final `'h'` and the 0-terminator go into `filepath. (Which is coincidental, since`sprintf`ing more into`command` than it can hold invokes undefined behaviour.)

Answer (score 3):

Unrelated to this problem, but you have an even more serious problem and that is this:

```
memcpy(&t1,localtime(&now),sizeof(t1));
```

Here you use `&t1`, which takes the address of the pointer, meaning you pass to `memset` a pointer to a pointer to a `struct tm`, in other words `struct tm **`. You also use `sizeof(t1)` which is the size of the pointer and not what it might point to, and depending on platform it will be four or eight bytes.

Since you directly afterward do

```
t1 = localtime(&now);
```

The `memset` call isn't actually needed.